# Glob not giving me any results

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP's Glob to get a list of files based on a wildcard, namely the extension.

```
$images = glob('/content/big/'.$item['id'].'.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

I know there is a file in this directory, namely: 23.png but it doesn't show in array $images. I don't have a clue why not. I've tried making the URL even more absolute (or explicit) like:

```
$images = glob('http://www.website.com/content/big/'.$item['id'].'.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Without result.

Could it be that Glob isn't installed properly inside PHP? Or is there another reason this doesn't give any results?

Comment: is there an absolute path `/content/big` on that server? Note that your path means server root, not document root. And urls dont work in glob as noted in the Notes section on the manual page.

Comment: As stated below, I did follow that path but got a bit lost after all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`glob` only works with paths on the server's file system, not URLs.

`http://www.website.com/content/big/` may really be `/var/www/site/content/big` on the server, and that's the path you need to use.

Staring a path with a `/` makes glob look in your root for that folder, and I'm assuming there is no folder called `/content/big/` on your server.

Try it like this (using a relative path from the server root):

```
$images = glob('content/big/'.$item['id'].'.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Or use an absolute path:

```
$images = glob('/var/www/site/content/big/'.$item['id'].'.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, that should be the solution and makes all the sense in the world. (Thus marked your answer as THE answer. Although I did try that already) But it doesn't seem to be the solution in my case, still no results in $images. Could there be something wrong with "my" Glob function??? I'm going to poke around some more, hope to find out where I (or something else ;) screwed up.

Comment: @tvgemert: Glad I could help.  I'd say double check your folder, make sure the files really are in there.  Also, try giving `glob` other folders to make sure it does give you results.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

below is my implementation, single quotes did not work with the echo, but this works for me. Hope it helps!

```
            <ul>
                    <?php
                            foreach(glob('audio/*.mp3') as $audio){ echo "<li><a>$audio</a></li>";}
                    ?>
            </ul>
```