# Google App Engine(php): glob() function

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I used glob() function in my application which is hosted on Google App Engine and my text_files are on Google Cloud Storage. It doesn't work and return false.
Here is the code:

```
$links = glob("gs://bucket_name/folder/textfile_*");
if($links){
    echo "true \n";
    print_r($links);
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

And my files on GCS are like this:

```
textfile_Ben.txt
textfile_Sam.txt
textfile_David.txt
```

I checked the http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php and it says:

> **Note**: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be
>   examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

My application works fine with other functions such `file_get_contents()` or `file_put_contents()`.

**Question**:
Is there any solution for using `glob()` function or is there any alternate method to do the same functionality?

Comment: glob won't work with a url, only file system paths. This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997887/glob-not-giving-me-any-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use opendir/readdir and filter the paths yourself.

Comment: It's the only way I reckon. The only issue is that it doesn't work with sub-directory. I can only use `opendir("gs://bucket_name/")` It doesn't work with `opendir("gs://bucket_name/folder/")`

Comment: You should be able to opendir a subfolder. If it's not working can you open an issue in the tracker?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "open an issue in the tracker" Where is tracker?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution :)

```
$folder = "gs://bucket_name/folder";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folder) as $fileInfo)
{
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

cheers