# undefined offset 9: looping to add all images in a folder

Tags: php, image, loops, offset, glob

I'm getting this error and i don't know why, especially since I found the code here on stack,

Hopefully this is something easily explain/fixable. I'm working on a beginning practice project and am currently learning how to use php to add all the images in a folder.

So, I have fpull.php with the code where the problem supposively lies, Line 9;

```
<?php 

$files = glob("../uploads/*.*");

for($x = 0; $x <= count($files); $x++){

    $image = $files[$x];
// ^ the line above is line 9 ^ --------------------

    echo '<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br/>";
}


?>
```

It wouldn't be a problem but it throws an error on my page,

Here is the index.php file that is included into.

```
<html>

<head>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<title>MOTIVATION</title>

</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" class="motivcall">

<label for="motivation">MotiVATOR</label>
<input type="text" size='50' name="motivation" id="motivation" placeholder="Enter your dose of Motivation">
<select name="dose">
    <option name="Oz">Oz</option>
    <option name="mg">Mg</option>
    <option name="mg">Kg</option>
    <option name="mg">Lb</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" name="submit">




<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   $motiv = $_POST['motivation'];

    if(isset($motiv)){

        for($x =0; $x <= $motiv; $x++){
    $vator = "You're Gonna Make It";
            echo "<h3>".$vator."</h3>";
     $actt = "Now Go Out There and Kick Some Ass";


        }

        echo " <h2>".$actt."</h2>";
}

}
?>
</form>

<br>

<?php

include('fpull.php');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show o/p of this `print_r($files);`

Comment: From php manual about glob "Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem."

Comment: The thing is, it works! Except at the very bottom after all the images, I get the error and a broken img file, even though it's displayed all the images..

Comment: User790454, I don't understand, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the = in <= in the for condition

Comment: ah nice.

Would you know why I'm still having a broken image icon after all of my images are displayed however?

Comment: I have something in my inbox 13 minutes ago that was a reply to here but it's not showing up, in otherwords I cannot read it,mind resending it? Anyone else know where he was going?

$folder = "../uploads/"; 
foreach (newDirectoryIterator($folder) as $fileinfo){e...

Comment: @av17 it was my answer before that I noticed the real problem. You can find a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193336/google-app-enginephp-glob-function