# PHP Select & Display Folder Images Not Showing

Tags: php, image

I have a peice of code that I was using for an old website and want to use it again in my new site, but the images aren't showing up for some reason.

The path to my gallery is correct and the code is a copy of an old working script. Can anyone suggest why this isn't working?

```
<?php
    $folder = 'http://localhost/website/magazine/photos/galleries/2016/gallery/';
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        echo '

            <div class=\"galleryCell\">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'">
                    <img class=\"galleryThumb\" src="'.$file.'" />
                    <div class=\"galleryThumbCover\"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

        ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: use $filetype ="*.jpg" or png  i think file type is required

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't solve the problem. It was `*.*` in the old code and that worked fine

Comment: I don't think you can access your gallery folder by using http or am I wrong?

Comment: @C0dekid.php I've tried all different variations of URL and nothing works

Comment: Thanks @C0dekid.php but that isn't a correct solution for me either.

Comment: one of the mistakes you made was to escape double quotes inside a single quoted echo statement, and error reporting would have probably thrown you something about it. The answer below hasn't fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use direct URL's for the `glob()` function. It needs the path of server folder e.g. `magazine/photos/galleries/2016/gallery/`. So your script would be something like this:

```
<?php
$folder = 'magazine/photos/galleries/2016/gallery/';
$filetype = '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype, GLOB_BRACE); # GLOB_BRACE for the multiple extensions (Using brackets)
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo '

        <div class="galleryCell">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'">
                <img class="galleryThumb" src="'.$file.'" />
                <div class="galleryThumbCover"></div>
            </a>
        </div>

    ';
}
?>
```

> Don't forget to change the path if I put the wrong path.

See reference: [Glob not giving me any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997887/glob-not-giving-me-any-results)

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks, but it just isn't echoing anything out at all!

Comment: @FootBlogger I have updated my answer, it should now working :-)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your coding help but it's just still not working. Do you know of any similar codes that will definitely work?

Comment: @FootBlogger you could use scandir [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226519/how-to-get-only-images-using-scandir-in-php), but I have one question.. where did you put the script to execute? In your `htdocs` or in the folder `/website`? If it's `htdocs` simply add `website/` before **magazine**

Comment: The php code shown above is inside `magazine/photos/view.php`

Comment: @FootBlogger than remove `magazine/photos/` in the `$folder` variable

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've done that and it's now recognising that there are 3 images. Just need to sort out the formatting now. Thanks!

Comment: Still got a problem that it's not picking up the CSS styling but I'm sure I'll sort that. Thanks again!

Comment: No I mean that `<img class=\"galleryThumb\"` isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Can you try to remove all the backslashes?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha you're welcome @FootBlogger! Just the little things that can make such big bugs, glad it's solved now, good luck with your project! :)

Comment: `<div class=\"galleryCell\">` etc. there's no need to escape the double quotes if the echo is wrapped in single quotes. The answer needs to be modified in order to show the right syntax, and this for future readers to the Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will be helpfull for you

```
 <?php
    $folder = '/magazine/photos/galleries/2016/gallery/';
    $filetype = '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}*';
    $files = glob($folder.$filetype,GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        echo '

            <div class=\"galleryCell\">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'">
                    <img class=\"galleryThumb\" src="'.$file.'" />
                    <div class=\"galleryThumbCover\"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

        ';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just isn't echoing anything out at all!